# Kohana 3.2, calling ORM table models(with has_many relationship) that are put inside a subfolder

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I was trying to organize my codes, in **application/classes/model/table/** (***table*** directory is just my own created folder), I put all the ORM table models to make it separated from other models.

With that, I also renamed my table models, for example from Model_Applicant >> Model_Table_Applicant then I put a table_name property to match.

Then in my controller, I can call this model by this code,

```
$applicantModel = ORM::factory('table_applicant');
```

My problem is, Model_Table_Applicant contains has_many property and I can't iterate the values.(Sorry i cant really put it in words so I will just post my codes).

**model/table/applicant.php**

```
class Model_Table_Applicant extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'applicants';

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'table_applicantSkill' => array()
    );
}
```

**model/table/applicantSkill.php**

```
class Model_Table_ApplicantSkill extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'applicant_skills';

}
```

And in my controller

```
public function action_testing() {
    $applicantModel = ORM::factory('table_applicant');
    foreach ($applicantModel->find_all() as $applicant) {
        echo $applicant->firstName.'<br>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($applicant->table_applicantSkill->find_all() as $applicantSkill) {
            echo '<li>'.$applicantSkill->skill.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is, it will echo "Alex" then a list of its skills but it just prints "Alex" then an error message

**Error Message**
*Unknown column 'table_applicantskill.table_applicant_id' in 'where clause' [ SELECT `table_applicantskill`...........*

Comment: Well, how is the structure of your table `applicant_skills`? Seems like the `table_applicant_id` field is missing

Comment: @kingkero applicant_skills has id, applicant_id, skill

Comment: and also, I already tried this before moving the model into tables folder. I got it to work

Comment: It needs to be `table_applicant_id` (as that is the default, just like described in the error message)

Comment: wait, I'll try to alter that table

Comment: If you don't want to alter the table, you can set the key in the model ([see Kohana doc](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany))

Comment: @kingkero thanks, its working now. But in that case, I have to rename the fields and putting "table_" in table fields looks ugly. Can you tell me some ways to solve my problems in separating ORM table models from other models?

Comment: Got to go now, will take a look at your question later that day (or someone else might be able to help you). But can you try to clearify that in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71024/discussion-between-alex-coroza-and-kingkero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with `ORM` it would make sense to write your own class that holds the important methods - mainly removing the *table_* prefix from values.

To do so, just create a file APPPATH/classes/ORM.php. The important method here is [`_initialize()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#_initialize), here the table name, foreign key as well as other values are set.

Just let Kohana do its thing and remove the prefix if necessary like so

```
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM
{
    protected static function remove_table_prefix($value)
    {
        $pattern = '/^table_(.*)$/i';
        $replace = '\\1';

        if (is_string($value))
        {
            return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
        }
        elseif (is_array($value))
        {
            foreach ($value as &$details)
            {
                $details['foreign_key'] = self::remove_table_prefix($details['foreign_key']);
            }
            return $value;
        }
        return $value;
    }

    protected function _initialize()
    {
        parent::_initialize();

        // remove "table_"
        $this->_table_name = self::remove_table_prefix($this->_table_name);
        $this->_belongs_to = self::remove_table_prefix($this->_belongs_to);
        $this->_has_one = self::remove_table_prefix($this->_has_one);
        $this->_has_many = self::remove_table_prefix($this->_has_many);
    }
}
```

You might have to modify that a bit further at other points, but locally it worked and you should get the idea.